# What does "やる事ブレない" mean?

Tags: translation

I ran into the word ブレ when looking for cameras. But after searching I've also seen it in this usage, like in here: http://metalpilldrums.cocolog-nifty.com/okazu/2011/12/index.html

> 清く正しく潔く、言う事やる事**ブレない**で生きたいねぇ

Does this have to do with the "deviation" meaning as japandict says? https://www.japandict.com/%E3%81%B6%E3%82%8C

Like "やる事ブレない" is "To not deviate from what I'm doing."

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "physical" meaning of ぶれる is "to deviate (from the correct position)" or "to be blurred". ぶれる also has a figurative meaning, "to waver", "(for one's opinion, policy, etc.) to become inconsistent", etc. Note that ブレる is an *intransitive* verb, and 言う事やる事 in your example is not its object.

> 言う事やる事ブレないで生きたい
>   = 言う事**や**やる事**が**ブレないように生きたい
>   (Literally) I want to live so that what I do or say does not waver.

The nuance is "I want to have a consistent principle/policy and live up to it."